# USB No Devices Available in Virtualbox 5.0.16 with Host Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Guest WinXP SP3

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox

I have worked for three days trying everything I could read on Virtualbox and Ubuntu forums, as well as the Virtualbox user manual. Finally I have given up. Does anyone know what else to do or if you can even run VB 5.0.16 on Ubuntu Host 14.04 LTS with Windows XP Guest and get USB devices to work?

USB Devices are not showing up  in Guest OS, even after following all the steps below...

**Host:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
**Guest:** Windows XP Service Pack 3
**Virtual Box 5.0.16** AMD with Extension Pack 5.0.16 installed
**Guest Additions 5.0** installed (mouse has integrated, shared folders, scalable window working)

- Username added to vboxuser group in host terminal
- Enabled USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller in VB.
- Plugged in USB device, Host recognized it.
- Tried to add USB Device to USB Device Filters list but there are “No Devices available”.
- Tried ejecting USB device from Host to see if Guest OS would see it then, but still “No Devices Available”.
- Tried entering USB device filters manually after printing out a USB log from Host terminal. Still “No Devices Available”.
- Looked in Registry to remove upper and lower filters. They did not exist, so did not do anything.
- Guest OS USB drivers un-installed and reinstalled.
- Getting no “error” messages at all.

I have exhausted all I can find on the forums and in the user manual. Any help beyond this is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the USB device?

Comment: Suggestions of things not in your quite exhaustive list: 1. Try with other USB devices 2. Reboot host 3. Reboot guest

Comment: Thanks Takkat, I have tried rebooting both host and guest. Also have tried plugging in my gps cable, printer cable, and 8GB usb stick. Still same message, "no devices available".

Comment: I was able to fix this by downgrading to VirtualBox 5.0.14. Cc @torahtom